# Opening up the previously viewed activity after killing the app KOTLIN

Tags: android, kotlin

In my app I have two activities, the first is the main activity/homepage that has buttons and the second displays an image. If the user is on the 2nd activity (ie. viewing an image) and they then close the app, killing it, how would I go about making it so that when I relaunch the app it shows the second activity with the image that the user was viewing?

I tried to add the following into the Manifest.xml

```
android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
```

So that the manifest looks as such:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SecondActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"

    /><activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    
    >
```

However, this does not work and the Main activity always opens...

Comment: how are you getting the image ? Is it an API call ? or is it saved locally ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way is by using SharedPreferences to store the state of the user.
If the user has viewed the Image, set the state to true.

And then in your MainActivity onCreate check the SharedPreference value, If it is true take the user to second screen.

Comment: Thanks, I know this question was very similar to others that had been asked but your answer just made it click for me!

Comment: Thanks , I am new to android and was searching for some questions where I could help someone. Really happy that my answer helped